# Pyaudio : Playback Error: 4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyaudio

Hello I am working with pyaudio to build a application that records and playbacks audio in realtime adding a low pass filter to the audio signal.
When I try to run this code this error below appears:

Pyaudio : Playback Error: 4

```
from pyaudio import PyAudio, paContinue, paFloat32
from time import sleep
from numpy import array, random, arange, float32, float64, zeros
import sounddevice as sd

fs            = 44100   # Hz
threshold     = 0.8     # absolute gain
delay         = 40      # samples
signal_length = 1      # second
release_coeff = 0.5555  # release time factor
attack_coeff  = 0.5     # attack time factor
dtype         = float32 # default data type
block_length  = 1024    # samples


class Limiter:
   def __init__(self, attack_coeff, release_coeff, delay, dtype=float32):
    self.delay_index = 0
    self.envelope = 0
    self.gain = 1
    self.delay = delay
    self.delay_line = zeros(delay, dtype=dtype)
    self.release_coeff = release_coeff
    self.attack_coeff = attack_coeff

def limit(self, signal, threshold):
    for i in arange(len(signal)):
        self.delay_line[self.delay_index] = signal[i]
        self.delay_index = (self.delay_index + 1) % self.delay

        # calculate an envelope of the signal
        self.envelope *= self.release_coeff
        self.envelope  = max(abs(signal[i]), self.envelope)

        # have self.gain go towards a desired limiter gain
        if self.envelope > threshold:
            target_gain = (1+threshold-self.envelope)
        else:
            target_gain = 1.0
        self.gain = ( self.gain*self.attack_coeff +
                      target_gain*(1-self.attack_coeff) )

        # limit the delayed signal
        signal[i] = self.delay_line[self.delay_index] * self.gain




    print "Recording Audio"
    signal = sd.rec(signal_length * fs, samplerate=fs, channels=1,    dtype=dtype)
    sd.wait()
    print "Audio recording complete , Play Audio"





original_signal = array(signal, copy=True, dtype=dtype)
limiter = Limiter(attack_coeff, release_coeff, delay, dtype)

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, flag):
    if flag:
        print("Playback Error: %i" % flag)
        played_frames = callback.counter
        callback.counter += frame_count
        limiter.limit(signal[played_frames:callback.counter], threshold)
    return signal[played_frames:callback.counter], paContinue

callback.counter = 0

pa = PyAudio()

stream = pa.open(format = paFloat32,
                 channels = 1,
                 rate = fs,
                 frames_per_buffer = block_length,
                 output = True,
                 stream_callback = callback)

while stream.is_active():
    sleep(0.1)

stream.close()
pa.terminate()
```

Comment: Give us a full traceback

Comment: Hello. I am new to python where do I put the code to get the trace back and what trace back code should I add. Thank you.

Comment: The traceback is the full error in red usually seen in the shell. The last line of the traceback should be the error: `Pyaudio : Playback Error: 4`

Comment: ok the trace back is: Recording Audio
Audio recording complete , Play Audio
Playback Error: 4
Playback Error: 4
Playback Error: 4
Playback Error: 4
Playback Error: 4
Playback Error: 4
Playback Error: 4

Answer (score 1):

You should not mix PyAudio and `sounddevice`!

Regardless of that, the functions [sounddevice.rec()](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#sounddevice.rec) and [sounddevice.wait()](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#sounddevice.wait) will not work correctly if they are called within a callback function (because they are using their own "stream" with their own callback function internally).

Comment: Ok . so what could be the solution.  The code is basically supposed  to record a mic and playback audio with a low pass filter to create a mubbling effect.

Comment: Those are 2 separate questions. If you show the code for your low pass filter, I can show you how to use it with `sounddevice`. Basically, you can just use the ["wire" example](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#callback-streams), apply your low-pass filter to `indata` and assign the result to `outdata[:]`. You only have to take care that the state of the filter is kept between consecutive callback calls.

Comment: Hello Matthias . I was give the code above as a way to add a limiter that is similar to a low pass filter. In a way creating a mubbling effect on the person speak on the mic. If you have code that does some thing similar please share. Thanks.

Comment: You should first try to implement a simple version of your limiter/filter/... that takes a single NumPy array and returns another array with the result. If you need help with the signal processing part, you should have a look at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/.